# Attention with Recurrent Neural Networks

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, attention

In RNNs, to avoid "forgetting" information encoded by earlier encoders, we can use attention. It's basically a second neural network that tells us how much we should attend at time *t* on each of the earlier hidden states (from *1* to *t - 1*).
This is described here:
[image]
(image from https://medium.com/swlh/a-simple-overview-of-rnn-lstm-and-attention-mechanism-9e844763d07b)

However, there is something I don't understand. This second neural network will output *t* values. So there will be *t* neurons on the last layer. What if my input sentence (in a seq2seq network for example) has only *t - 2* words. Or *t + 2* words. Then I can't use that same second neural network since its architecture is fixed. How is it dealt?

EDIT: is it that the second neural network takes as input one encoder hidden state and one decoder hidden state, and we get *t* scores by doing *t* forward passes (one per each input hidden state, all with the current decoder hidden state)? And then we softmax all those *t* outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need padding for attention with variable-length inputs. Looking at the formulation in the article:
[image: Attention description from article: https://medium.com/swlh/a-simple-overview-of-rnn-lstm-and-attention-mechanism-9e844763d07b]

A learned model ($\mathbf{a}(\cdot)$) encodes the hidden state of each input token directly. This means that if you have a longer/shorter input, you would just run more forward-passes.

During training, $\mathbf{a}(\cdot)$ learns to give higher values for more relevant tokens. It only depends on the hidden-dimensions of $h_j$ and $s_{t-1}$. You might still use masking and padding, this generally is more of a efficiency thing (because GPUs like static data sizes). In fact, you'll probably have to use masking to make sure that your decoder doesn't attend to masking tokens.

Comment: Oh I see, so we just do as many forward passes as potential hidden states we want to attend to, each forward pass giving a score and then we apply a softmax!

Comment: Yep, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

Two concepts are critical here: masking and padding.

From [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/understanding_masking_and_padding):

> **Masking** is a way to tell sequence-processing layers that certain
> timesteps in an input are missing, and thus should be skipped when
> processing the data.
>
> **Padding** is a special form of masking where the masked steps are at the
> start or the end of a sequence. Padding comes from the need to encode
> sequence data into contiguous batches: in order to make all sequences
> in a batch fit a given standard length, it is necessary to pad or
> truncate some sequences.

See the article for more details.

Also see [Introduction to Recurrent Neural Networks with Keras and TensorFlow by Aritra Roy Gosthipaty, Devjyoti Chakraborty, and Ritwik Raha](https://pyimagesearch.com/2022/07/25/introduction-to-recurrent-neural-networks-with-keras-and-tensorflow/). See the section entitled ["A Caveat: Masking and Padding"](https://pyimagesearch.com/2022/07/25/introduction-to-recurrent-neural-networks-with-keras-and-tensorflow/#h2Caveat).

Prudhviraju Srivatsavaya explains the concepts in reference to Transformers in his article [Attention Masks - Explanation](https://medium.com/@prudhviraju.srivatsavaya/attention-masks-explanation-b4ee2e8f8d23).

Comment: So does that mean attention has a set length and if we have let's say more input tokens that its set length it would not be able to provide attention to *any* previous hidden states?